How to determine which compression method is being used on a block of data?
I have a program that reads files from an older system.  One section of data in each file (not the whole file) is compressed using an unknown compression scheme, which I need to know how to decompress.  I have examples of data before and after it has been compressed.  I'm not sure how to determine the compression scheme, and was hoping someone here might know how to figure this out.  Based on some Googling, the most common compression scheme seems to be Huffman coding, though after implementing that and testing it, that doesn't seem to be the one that's used.
Here is an example of a section of data before compression (in hex bytes):
00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF EC 02 00 00 23 03 00 00 23 03 00 00 03 03 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 55 03 00 00 00 00 01 01 09 04 04 04 09 09 09 09 07 09 00 06 00 7C 00 1F 55 01 00 C9 1F 54 01 00 07 00 F7 00 2F 54 53 01 00 05 11 54 3D 00 2F 53 52 01 00 03 11 53 57 00 4F 53 53 52 51 01 00 01 20 52 53 1C 00 6E 53 53 52 52 51 50 01 00 02 1F 00 00 58 00 1F 51 1F 00 08 00 58 00 0E 3C 00 05 3E 00 0F 3A 00 01 00 02 00 03 5D 00 0F 1F 00 FF 63 00 B3 01 0F 02 00 01 05 F0 01 0F 02 00 04 03 2E 02 0F 02 00 06 01 6C 02 0F 02 00 03 50 54 54 54 54 54 01 00 00 00 06 00 42 00 1F 55 01 00 C5 1F 54 01 00 0C 1F 53 01 00 09 4F 54 54 53 52 01 00 07 01 1F 00 1F 51 01 00 05 03 1F 00 1F 50 01 00 03 0F 1F 00 FF C7 0F 0F 02 0B 0F 4D 02 0B 0F 8B 02 0B 0F 02 00 06 50 54 54 54 54 54 54 00 00 00 06 00 83 00 1F 55 01 00 C5 1C 54 01 00 0A E9 00 2A 54 53 01 00 03 2E 00 04 25 00 38 54 53 52 01 00 03 2C 00 03 25 00 66 54 54 54 53 52 51 01 00 03 2A 00 03 25 00 00 27 00 44 53 52 51 50 01 00 03 28 00 03 25 00 2B 52 52 1F 00 02 02 00 03 25 00 2F 51 51 1F 00 03 04 02 00 0F 1F 00 FF 89 00 BD 01 0F 02 00 01 02 D1 01 00 F9 01 0F 02 00 03 00 0F 02 00 35 02 0F 02 00 05 01 6F 02 0F 02 00 03 50 54 54 54 54 54 A7 00 00 00 0B 00 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 12 13 14 15 17 17 17 17 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 13 14 16 17 17 17 17 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 13 17 17 17 17 17 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 12 16 17 17 16 16 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 12 16 16 16 15 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 13 15 15 14 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 13 14 14 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10

and here is the same section after compression:
E2 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF EC 02 00 00 23 03 04 00 20 03 03 12 00 04 02 00 20 55 03 24 00 F1 85 01 01 09 04 04 04 09 09 09 09 07 09 00 06 00 7C 00 1F 55 01 00 C9 1F 54 01 00 07 00 F7 00 2F 54 53 01 00 05 11 54 3D 00 2F 53 52 01 00 03 11 53 57 00 4F 53 53 52 51 01 00 01 20 52 53 1C 00 6E 53 53 52 52 51 50 01 00 02 1F 00 00 58 00 1F 51 1F 00 08 00 58 00 0E 3C 00 05 3E 00 0F 3A 00 01 00 02 00 03 5D 00 0F 1F 00 FF 63 00 B3 01 0F 02 00 01 05 F0 01 0F 02 00 04 03 2E 02 0F 02 00 06 01 6C 02 0F 02 00 03 50 54 54 54 54 54 01 00 00 00 06 00 42 84 00 10 C5 84 00 90 0C 1F 53 01 00 09 4F 54 54 7E 00 F0 02 07 01 1F 00 1F 51 01 00 05 03 1F 00 1F 50 01 00 03 56 00 D0 C7 0F 0F 02 0B 0F 4D 02 0B 0F 8B 02 0B 51 00 02 4A 00 11 54 4A 00 12 83 4A 00 80 1C 54 01 00 0A E9 00 2A CD 00 71 03 2E 00 04 25 00 38 51 00 80 03 2C 00 03 25 00 66 54 5F 00 50 51 01 00 03 2A 0F 00 51 00 27 00 44 53 D3 00 20 03 28 10 00 70 2B 52 52 1F 00 02 02 0B 00 90 2F 51 51 1F 00 03 04 02 00 79 00 30 89 00 BD C8 00 60 01 02 D1 01 00 F9 0A 00 60 03 00 0F 02 00 35 CE 00 30 05 01 6F 07 00 03 D5 00 7A A7 00 00 00 0B 00 10 01 00 8A 12 13 14 15 17 17 17 17 16 00 5F 10 11 13 14 16 17 00 00 30 10 10 13 16 00 0C 2E 00 80 10 10 12 16 17 17 16 16 0A 00 0A 02 00 5A 12 16 16 16 15 13 00 01 02 00 41 13 15 15 14 09 00 0B 02 00 2F 13 14 17 00 02 0F 02 00 06 1A 11 1A 00 50 10 10 10 10 10

Here's what I know about the data:
-The length of the data after compression is variable.
-There is no common prefix for the data (the first byte varies).
I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me determine the compression scheme being used, or even point me in the right direction.

Look for tools for this problem.

Why did you remove the data from your question?

Because someone I work with might recognize the data pattern and then I'll get fired [laughing-but-also-crying-emoji]

Also seems to me that this is a question about a very specific scenario that wouldn't be relevant to anyone else.  It won't let me delete the question, which is fine, so I just tried to remove the specific/potentially sensitive data.

@LanTanben Now that you have the answer, I suggest creating artificial data by choosing an arbitrary sequence of bytes and then applying lz4 on that!

It is lz4 output with some bytes stripped off. If I use lz4 -l (legacy) on your input, and then strip off the first eight bytes, I get exactly your output.

Hi! Would you consider describing the process that led you to that answer? Did you recognise the lz4 encoding? Or did you try several encoding programs to see which matched?

Thanks for the answer!  I tested it using just basic LZ4 and it's worked on every file I've tested so far (about 15,000).  I didn't even have to remove the first eight bytes.

I noticed lots of 0 and 1 bytes in the compressed data, suggesting rather poor compression. That led me to try lz4, which is one of the few commonly-used compressors with compression like that, in exchange for being very fast.

Interesting.  Thanks for the insight.  And thanks again for helping me.  It probably would've taken me weeks of trial and error to figure it out, assuming I eventually did.
